# How to ignore error when Entity Framework property marked Obsolete?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

See the following entity class:

```
[Table("order")]
public class McaTransaction : IValidatableObject
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public decimal Id { get; set; }
    [Obsolete("Remove as we should not be linking this data back to the CMS")]
    public int SiteNodeId { get; set; }
    public string PartnerCode { get; set; }
    public string PartnerName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; } 
}
```

Whenever I try to add the 'SiteNodeId' in the filter criteria (or where clause), it throws the error that 'SiteNodeId' is obsolete.

I do not understand, does that mean that I cannot filter the records on the basis of 'SiteNodeId'?

Comment: You mean "obsolete," not "absolute," right?

Comment: The code shown should only generate a warning. But there's a project setting (under Build) where you can tell it to treat warnings as errors. Maybe that's set?

Comment: yes dasblinkenlight its obsolute, sorry for type.